What type(s) of normal games are solvable by the strategy stealing argument?
I am aware that the strategy stealing argument applies to symmetric games where having an extra move is never a disadvantage.
However, I'm unsure of a term for that state inside combinatorial game theory - specifically, the class of normal games.
My intuition would lead me to believe that hot games are solvable by the strategy-stealing argument, but I was wondering if there is any concrete class or type of game to which the strategy-stealing argument can always be applied.

I think it's at least true for a game $g$ if $g=-g$ and $g$ isn't a cold game (i.e. a number which under the previous condition could only be $0$). However, this sounds so obvious as to be uninteresting.

It's still a good observation!

How do you define "strategy-stealing argument" if you intend it to apply to games that are not of the literal form $G+(-G)$? I mean I understand what you mean for tic-tac-toe, but do you have a definition in mind?

@TristanF.-R. Actually, I think I may have made a mistake in my comment. Now that think about it more thoroughly, I don't know how to steal a strategy in general in such a case (though that class of games is still obviously a first mover win).

@MarkS. (I believe G - G = 0 is proved by a symmetric argument, distinct from the strategy stealing argument.) I'm mainly considering whether there is a way to describe what it means for an extra move to never be a disadvantage.
My first immediate guess would be to say that that condition would hold for G if there exists some left move G^(L_1) such that G || G^(L_1)

Here is another example of a strategy stealing argument. Let $G$ be an impartial game, and then let $H=G\cup {G}$. Strategy-stealing proves that $H$ is a first player win. Either $G$ is a first-player win, and the winning option for $G$ is also a winning option for $H$ (this is the stealing part), or $G$ is a second player win, so the winning move is $H\to G$. This argument proves Chomp is a first player win. I wonder if there is a general definition of strategy-stealing which includes both the maker-breaker games, as well as this example.
